# Equivalent of WebFileType in v5 Bing Search API?

Tags: bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

As Microsoft is shutting down the v2 Bing Search API on Azure Data Market, I'm currently researching how to migrate to the v5 Bing Search that's part of Microsoft Cognitive Services, as suggested.

What I used v2 for was to search the web for feeds (RSS, Atom) only. This actually worked extremely well and reliable with v2 - I used the WebFileType parameter for it like this:

> ?Query='SearchText'&WebFileType='FEED'

Note: I removed URI encoding for readability.

Now I searched the documentation for the new API but I did not find any possibility to apply filters like this.

Is there a way to do that? If not, I would have to abandon Bing unfortunately - in this case, does anyone have any recommendations which service can provide me with similar capabilities?

Comment: we are looking into your inquiry. I sent this request to our internal engineering team to validate if the 'WebFileType parameter Query='SearchText'&WebFileType='FEED' is supported on the new version of the API. Thank you

Comment: @Patrick Thanks, very much appreciated. In the meantime, I found this document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt707570.aspx#composite that states there is no equivalent in v5 for WebFileType. So the question is if there is any other way to achieve what I did in V2 or will such features be added to V5 in the near future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a [comment from Václav on UserVoice](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/555907-bing-search/suggestions/16482313-support-for-bing-api-v2-webfiletype-query-paramete), one can use the standard bing.com query syntax right in the search query. In case you want to search for feeds, that would work with a `feed:` prefix to the query, like:

```
feed:Engadget
```

As Václav points out, this is undocumented and as such very unlikely to be supported and can stop working at any time. But it's at least something for now, facing the December 15 shutdown deadline of the current V2 API and really no alternatives I know of, yet.